# CSS background url attribute does not display any image on the webpage

Tags: html, css

I use the atom text editor in MacOS. Web browser google chrome and have not noticed any difficulties except for this one. If is use the  in html, my image displays on the web page but when I create a seperate div and try to assign the image via CSS using background: url(image url). my image is in the same folder as my html file and my css file. but it just doesn't appear. I have made sure to check for any spelling errors too.

HTML

```
        <div class="container">
            <p>
                L
            </p>
        </div>
        <header>
            <h1>Parallax Effect</h1>
        </header>
```

CSS

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Monument Extended", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: inherit;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

header,
header:before {
    background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

header::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    background: url(HERO.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    transform-origin: center center 0;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100vh;
    background: black;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 40px;
    color: grey;
}
```

Comment: The problem might be in the path to the image.

Comment: Try to put double quotes for the `background: url("HERO.jpeg");`

Comment: @BARNI It's in the same folder. It shouldn't require any path, but I still tried to add a path but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Lievno I tried double single and no quotes it does not work

Comment: Works for me! https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/5aj3gvLf/118/

Comment: Can you check in the console if the image is found or not?

Comment: @BARNI the console shows this "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: So it means you have not entered correct path to image. Can you write your path to css file and path to image?

Comment: a project folder on my desktop, which contains the image "HERO.jpeg", the html file "home-parralax.html" and the css file "home-parralax.css". so "\project\HERO.jpeg", "\project\home-parralax.css"

Comment: maybe you are not including CSS file in your HTML, or even it has some wrong path to it?

Comment: @BARNI but all the other CSS attributes show in the webpage, only the image is not absent

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you are using z-index and transform-style, but you can use this w3schools tutorial instead:
[Parallax Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

Also, I second the comment talking about quotations: whenever referencing any file, use these -> ""

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing quotes on background: url(Users/aniket/Desktop/transenergy/HERO.jpeg);
Try like this instead 
background: url("Users/aniket/Desktop/transenergy/HERO.jpeg");

Comment: nah that doesn't work either. the console says "the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Well it works for me here it tried with external image https://codepen.io/shqipdon-selmani/pen/eYpNzxO if it still not working you have to check the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Try not only to add the quotes, but to review your path, for example ("./HERO.jpeg"), otherwise try with other formats.